# seleccionar valor máximo y mínimo de una lista con sublistas

Tags: python

Buenas tengo el siguiente arreglo, y deseo seleccionar el valor máximo y mínimo de dicho arreglo, cómo puedo hacerlo?

```
ytra01=[array([1.18182126307657e-125, -0.0119506376551417, -0.0238653670087153,
        -0.0357093641553568, -0.0474489881673787, -0.0590517810947708,
        -0.0704864679651997, -0.0817229567840087, -0.0927323385342183,
        -0.103486887176526, -0.113960059649305, -0.124126495868608,
        -0.133962018728162, -0.143443634099373, -0.152549530831321,
        -0.161259080750767, -0.169552838662145, -0.177412542347568,
        -0.184821112566827, -0.191762653057386, -0.198222450534390,
        -0.204186974690659, -0.209643878196690, -0.214581996700658,
        -0.218991348828412, -0.222863136183482, -0.226189743347072,
        -0.228964737878063, -0.231182870313016, -0.232840074166164,
        -0.233933465929421, -0.234461345072376, -0.234423194042295,
        -0.233819678264123, -0.232652646140478, -0.230925129051658,
        -0.228641341355637, -0.225806680388066, -0.222427726462272,
        -0.218512242869262, -0.214069175877715, -0.209108654733991,
        -0.203641991662125, -0.197681681863830, -0.191241403518495,
        -0.184336017783187, -0.176981568792647, -0.169195283659298,
        -0.160995572473234, -0.152402028302231, -0.143435427191739,
        -0.134117728164886, -0.124472073222477, -0.114522787342993,
        -0.104295378482593, -0.0938165375751110, -0.0831141385320608,
        -0.0722172382426312, -0.0611560765736884, -0.0499620763697752,
        -0.0386678434531117, -0.0273071666235948, -0.0159150176587985,
        -0.00452755131397313, 0.00681789467795345, 0.0180827996063767,
        0.0292274597830153, 0.0402109885419106, 0.0509913162394275,
        0.0615251902542539, 0.0717681749874005, 0.0816746518622012,
        0.0911978193243132, 0.100289692841717, 0.108901104904715,
        0.116981705025934, 0.124479959740323, 0.131343152605155,
        0.137517384200026, 0.142947572126853, 0.147577451009879,
        0.151349572495669, 0.154205305253110, 0.156084834973414,
        0.156927164370114, 0.156670113179067, 0.155250318158455,
        0.152603233088780, 0.148663128772868, 0.143363093035869,
        0.136635030725257, 0.128409663710825, 0.118616530884694,
        0.107183988161304, 0.0940392084774217, 0.0791081817921341,
        0.0623157150868521, 0.0435854323653106, 0.0228397746535661,
        -3.25260651745651e-16], dtype=object),
 array([1.18182126307657e-125, -0.0249772674435424, -0.0519907845042112,
        -0.0809050263018950, -0.111586833911836, -0.143905414364630,
        -0.177732340646228, -0.212941551697932, -0.249409352416401,
        -0.287014413653646, -0.325637772217032, -0.365162830869278,
        -0.405475358328457, -0.446463489267996, -0.488017724316676,
        -0.530030930058630, -0.572398339033347, -0.615017549735669,
        -0.657788526615792, -0.700613600079266, -0.743397466486994,
        -0.786047188155233, -0.828472193355595, -0.870584276315045,
        -0.912297597215901, -0.953528682195836, -0.994196423347878,
        -1.03422207872041, -1.07352927231715, -1.11204399409721,
        -1.14969459997501, -1.18641181182037, -1.22212871745841,
        -1.25678077066966, -1.29030579118996, -1.32264396471053,
        -1.35373784287793, -1.38353234329408, -1.41197474951625,
        -1.43901471105707, -1.46460424338452, -1.48869772792194,
        -1.51125191204800, -1.53222590909676, -1.55158119835760,
        -1.56928162507529, -1.58529340044991, -1.59958510163693,
        -1.61212767174716, -1.62289441984676, -1.63186102095725,
        -1.63900551605550, -1.64430831207375, -1.64775218189956,
        -1.64932226437588, -1.64900606430099, -1.64679345242853,
        -1.64267666546750, -1.63665030608224, -1.62871134289246,
        -1.61885911047322, -1.60709530935493, -1.59342400602335,
        -1.57785163291959, -1.56038698844014, -1.54104123693682,
        -1.51982790871680, -1.49676290004262, -1.47186447313217,
        -1.44515325615869, -1.41665224325077, -1.38638679449237,
        -1.35438463592278, -1.32067585953667, -1.28529292328403,
        -1.24827065107025, -1.20964623275603, -1.16945922415744,
        -1.12775154704592, -1.08456748914824, -1.03995370414653,
        -0.993959211678288, -0.946635397336348, -0.898036012668906,
        -0.848217175179511, -0.797237368327065, -0.745157441525825,
        -0.692040610145400, -0.637952455510755, -0.582960924902207,
        -0.527136331555429, -0.470551354661445, -0.413281039366636,
        -0.355402796772732, -0.296996403936824, -0.238144003871350,
        -0.178930105544105, -0.119441583878238, -0.0597676797522508,
        -6.50521303491303e-16], dtype=object)]
```

deberia arrojarme los valores 0.1569 (maximo) y  -1.649 minimo he aplicado esto pero no salen los valores correctos

```
float(max(ytra01, key = lambda x: x[2])[0])
float(min(ytra01, key = lambda x: x[2])[0])
```

agradezco su ayuda

Answer (score 1):

Con `float(max(ytra01, key = lambda x: x[2])[0])` estas obteniendo el array anidado (`x`) cuyo tercer elemento (`x: x[2]`) es mayor y luego obtienes el primer elemento de dicho array  (`[0]`), en tu caso `1.18182126307657e-125` en ambos casos.

Si quieres el máximo y mínimo de uno de los subarrays, por ejemplo el segundo deberías simplemente indizar:

```
>>> max(ytra01[1])
1.18182126307657e-125
```

Si quieres el máximo y mínimo teniendo en cuenta los valores de todos los subarrays:

```
>>> max(max(sub) for sub in ytra01)
0.156927164370114

>>> min(min(sub) for sub in ytra01)
-1.64932226437588
```

No obstante, dado que pareces estar usando NumPy (directa o indirectamente), deberías usar `numpy.min` y `numpy.max`:

```
 >>> import numpy as np

 >>> np.min(ytra01)
 -1.64932226437588

 >>> np.max(ytra01)
 0.156927164370114
```

Si `ytra01` es un array NumPy también puedes simplemente hacer:

```
>>> ytra01.min()
>>> ytra01.max()
```

Esto es si quieres el valor mínimo/máximo teniendo en cuenta todos los subarrays, si quieres el valor mínimo teniendo en cuenta  solo el segundo, simplemente indexa:

```
>>> ytra01[1].min()
>>> ytra01[1].max()
```

Si quieres los valores máximo y mínimo para cada subarray usa `numpy.amin` y `numpy.amax`:

```
>>> np.amax(ytra01, axis=1))
[0.156927164370114 1.18182126307657e-125]

>>> np.amin(ytra01, axis=1))
[-0.234461345072376 -1.64932226437588]
```